# How to tell Windows 7 that an application does not need to run with admin rights?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, uac, elevation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent elevation (UAC) for an application that doesn't need it](https://superuser.com/questions/24631/prevent-elevation-uac-for-an-application-that-doesnt-need-it)

I am using an application that was written before Windows Vista/Windows 7. Windows has decided that the application needs to run as an admin (i.e., it has the shield icon). I'm pretty sure the application has nothing in its manifest that indicates that it needs to run with elevated privileges (it was written way before Windows Vista).

Is there any way to tell Windows that a specific application does not need elevated privileges?

Answer (score 14):

Windows automatically elevates applications based on various criteria (listed in [Understanding and Configuring User Account Control in Windows Vista](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709628%28WS.10%29.aspx)):

> Before a 32 bit process is created,
>   the following attributes are checked
>   to determine whether it is an
>   installer:
>
> - Filename includes keywords like "install," "setup," "update," etc.
> - Keywords in the following Versioning Resource fields: Vendor, Company Name, Product Name, File Description, Original Filename, Internal Name, and Export Name.
> - Keywords in the side-by-side manifest embedded in the executable.
> - Keywords in specific StringTable entries linked in the executable.
> - Key attributes in the RC data linked in the executable.
> - Targeted sequences of bytes within the executable.

If you can't prevent elevation by renaming the file, you should be able to [create a manifest that prevents elevation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Comment: That auto elevations based on keywords is sick!

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the program was properly written, and will actually *work* when running as a standard user, you can manifest it to run as standard user.

> **Note**: If the program didn't work on Windows XP, it will continue to fail on Windows Vista or Windows 7. You can test this application by logging into Windows XP and seeing if it works. (You ***do*** login to Windows XP as a standard user, right?)
>
> If the program fails to run correctly on Windows XP as a standard user, it will fail to run on Windows 7 as a standard user. If you must run the program as an administrator on Windows XP, you must run the program as an administrator on Windows 7.

If you're satisfied that the program doesn't need to be run as an administrator, you can add a *Manifest* instruction Windows that it should be run as the standard user that you are.

Create the manifest file in the same folder as your application. e.g., `Goldwave.exe` you create:

**`Goldwave.exe.manifest`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0"
     processorArchitecture="X86"
     name="IsUserAdmin"
     type="win32"/> 
  <description>Description of your application</description> 
  <!-- Identify the application security requirements. -->
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

**Note:** This is a so-called *external* manifest, because it's in a separate file. It's entirely possible that the application already *has* a manifest.

> Manifests were introduced with Windows 2000 as a way to declare dependencies on certain versions of DLLs. One common use of that manifest came along with Windows XP, for programs to declare their dependancy on **version 6** of `comctl32.dll` – so that the application was "themed".

If the application already has an *embedded* manifest, Windows will ignore any *external* manifest. In that case you'd need to use [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to modify the embedded `RT_MANIFEST` (resource type 24) manifest.

---

The next thing you can do is check the registry to see if someone's already applied an *elevate* shim to your program.  Load Regedit and check:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags
    \Layers
```

In there you will likely find a large number of programs listed, with their space-separated shims:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\ACDSee32\ACDSee32.exe  `HIGHDPIAWARE`
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Picasa3\Picasa3.exe `ELEVATECREATEPROCESS`
- C:\Program Files (x86)\skiStunt\skiStunt\bin\skiStunt.exe `WINXPSP2`
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe `HIGHDPIAWARE ELEVATECREATEPROCESS`
- C:\Program Files (x86)\SysInternals\autoruns.exe `ELEVATECREATEPROCESS RUNASADMIN`
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Messenger\msnmsgr.exe `VISTASP2`
- D:\Games\Call of Duty\CoDSP.exe `WINXPSP3`
- D:\Shared\Win32app\Spy\SPYXX.EXE `DISABLEDWM`

Check that your program isn't in there. You can also find a similar set of entries (the ones for "*all users*") in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers
```

Comment: How do the shims get there?

Comment: @MichaelSlade When you check options on a program's property's **Compatibility** tab. Those settings are saved in the registry `AppCompatFlags` key

Comment: Is there any reason an executable is still requesting for Elevation running under a standard user account, even when the manifest was edited to specify <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/> ?

Comment: @Sajuuk I've seen such a thing happen. Windows has decided that my app needs to elevate, and i don't want it to elevate. So i add an assembly manifest, and confirm the assembly manifest **is** being used, but running it still triggers a UAC elevation. The cause is that Windows has (somewhere) cached the fact that `Project1.exe` needs elevation, and it remembers that until the system is restarted.

Answer (score 1):

If the application was written well before Windows Vista / 7, then there's a good chance that it could require admin rights to run. A lot of programs assumed that the person installing would have admin rights, so they just wrote to the sections of the registry and file system the programmer thought best.

I know this from my own personal experience. About a decade ago I was working for a company that sold its software into a big automotive company. All their PCs were locked down.
We had to modify our code so it could be installed by some one running with just "User" rights.