# How to deny elevation to a program?

Tags: windows-vista, uac, privileges, elevation

Does Windows have an *"automatically deny elevation request"* list?

If a user is a *"standard user"*, it is possible to have Windows [automatically deny any elevation requests](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_StandardUserPromptBehavior) by changing the [`ConsentPromptBehaviorUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc232762%28v=prot.10%29.aspx) group policy setting to [*Automatically deny elevation requests*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_StandardUserPromptBehavior):

- `Prompt for credentials on the secure desktop.` (**Default**) When an operation requires elevation of privilege, the user is prompted on the secure desktop to enter a different user name and password. If the user enters valid credentials, the operation continues with the applicable privilege
- `Prompt for credentials` When an operation requires elevation of privilege, the user is prompted to enter an administrative user name and password. If the user enters valid credentials, the operation continues with the applicable privilege
- **`Automatically deny elevation requests`** When an operation requires elevation of privilege, a configurable access denied error message is displayed. An enterprise that is running desktops as standard user may choose this setting to reduce help desk calls

> This is useful in a situation where a program might prompt to elevate, but that would require the guy from helpdesk to run three buildings over (to enter their *over the shoulder* credentials). Only once they get there, they discover that the user shouldn't run that program.
>
> We *want* the application to run as a standard user (possibly getting *access denied* errors), since that's the correct answer.

But that setting applies to *all* programs that elevate. Is it possible to

- mark a program, or
- add it to a list

so that it is automatically denied elevation requests, and runs as a standard user?

The problem happens when a program has been mistakenly:

- marked as `requestedExecutionLevel` of `requireAdministrator` in its embedded or external manifest
- has had the "Run this program has an administrator" compatibility option checked
- is being detected as a setup program (e.g., is named `install` or `setup`) through the [`EnableInstallerDetection`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_DetectApp) heuristics

**Note:** *Assuming* the application had no manifest, one might suggest adding a manifest indicating `requestedExecutionLevel: asInvoker`. This solution would also disable file and registry virtualization for the application.

### See also

- [Prevent elevation (UAC) for an application that doesn't need it](https://superuser.com/questions/24631/prevent-elevation-uac-for-an-application-that-doesnt-need-it) *(no solution found)*
- [How to tell Windows 7 that an application does not need to run with admin rights?](https://superuser.com/questions/102975/how-to-tell-windows-7-that-an-application-does-not-need-to-run-with-admin-rights) *(answer for that situation is to add a manifest*)
- [How to determine why application is prompting for elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831967/how-to-determine-why-application-is-prompting-for-elevation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to use two policies in concert:

1. Configure the already mentioned *ConsentPromptBehaviorUser* group
   policy setting to *Automatically deny elevation requests*. As stated
   in the question, this will affect all programs that run.
2. Next ENABLE the [User Account Control: Only elevate executables that
   are signed and validated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835564%28v=WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_ElevateSigned) policy setting. (From Microsoft) This
   setting enforces public key infrastructure (PKI) signature checks
   for any interactive applications that request elevation of
   privilege. Enterprise administrators can control which applications
   are allowed to run by adding certificates to the Trusted Publishers
   certificate store on local computers.
3. Sign any trusted programs with your organization's key and publish it to
   the Trusted Publishers certificate store on all computers in your
   organization. [More info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01daf08f.aspx)

Comment: Accepted because there's almost certainly no answer; and these workarounds would be the best one can get.