# Is there a tool that will automatically fix programs requesting elevation when they don't need it

Tags: windows, uac, elevation

I have heard of the external manifest trick to get programs not to ask for elevation when they really don't need it.

Is there a program that will automatically modify or add a manifest to an executable declaring that it does not need elevation. It is fine even if that program itself needs elevation to do it. Since it should only have to do it once per program.

I ask this since because there is a chance the external manifest doesn't work, and then fixing it gets involved. Also the problem that the external manifest could change information about the application. Such as its description.

Comment: Adding a link to the 'external manifest trick' might help here.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/102975

Comment: This is another approach that might solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7538190/886887