# What is a "loader flag" in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, uac

I was following the accepted solution to the following SuperUser question, which recommends the use of the Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit to apply the RunAsInvoker fix:

[Prevent elevation (UAC) for an application that doesn't need it](https://superuser.com/questions/24631/prevent-elevation-uac-for-an-application-that-doesnt-need-it)

While doing more research into this topic, I found the following Microsoft TechNet article, which describes how the RunAsInvoker fix works:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638389.aspx

The article states:

> This compatibility fix does not intercept any APIs; instead, it applies a **loader flag** to the application.

I tried Googling for more information about what a "loader flag" is in this context, but Google gave no relevant results. What is a "loader flag" in Windows, and can a "loader flag" be set programmatically?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx

Comment: @SeanCheshire What's the link about? I'm not following.

Comment: the page describes the *manifest* file that contains the flags. a resource editor like [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) can let you view the information that a windows EXE file contains, such as the manifest

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question.

The "loader" that the TechNet article refers to is the Windows Image Loader, as described in Chapter 3, Section 10 of Russinovich's *Windows Internals, Fifth Edition*:

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/microsoft-windows/9780735625303/system-mechanisms/image_loader